# Calling a custom java or js function on receiving react native firebase message without tapping notification. (Specially in killed state)

Tags: react-native, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, messaging, react-native-firebase

My use case is to store a notification and show it whenever the user opens the react native app as an inapp popup and not just on the notification tray (especially when the app is in killed state).

Is there a functionality in react native firebase messaging that I may be missing or the library does not provide this feature?

The only way I can think of doing it is to make change in library code and intercept the notification from there.